# Automatically run selenium python daily on certain time

Tags: python, selenium, bots, schedule

I would like to run a selenium python bot automatically on daily basis on 7pm US time , i believe this could be solved by schedule.
i've tried the below but sounds not complete:
schedule.every(1).day

Comment: @undetectedSelenium could you please help me on that

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by task scheduler

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).